# NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sdk

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

indicates that I have .net8.0.1 installed.

[image: versions]

My c# Solution has .Net7 and .Net8 projects and builds OK.

If I change the main project to have

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0.101-windows</TargetFramework>
```

When I build I get

> NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET
> 8.0.1.  Either target .NET 8.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0.1. Download the .NET SDK from
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

[Update]
This is what I see in my bin\debug folder
[image]

I deleted the obj and build folders. Now when I attempt to build I get
[NetSDK1004](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1004?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(NETSDK1004)%26rd%3Dtrue)

I am using VS17.8.5

Comment: I believe you are supposed to write `net8.0-windows` without the minor versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reinstalled the latest sdk which was v8.0.101
cleaned
rebuilt
Now I only have the bin\debug\net8.0-windows folder as desired.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, on visual studio for MAC 17.6.8, I had to select the following option:

***Visual Studio*** => ***Preferences*** => ***Others*** => ***Preview Features*** => ***Use .NET 8 SDK if installed***

Even though the version of .net8 I installed was not a preview version, I still had to select this option

Answer (score 1):

If you use Visual Studio 2022 you have to upgrade to version 17.8+.
More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1455577/upgrading-c-net-core-7-0-to-8-0-in-visual-studio-i).

Answer (score 0):

When looking at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-8.0.101-windows-x64-installer it says that it is only supported for version of VS2022 (v17.8), for other versions of VS you can find the SDK available on [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks)

Or check the Directory.build.props, it is an optional file that can override your desired settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error as in below when I was changing the `TargetFramework` from `net6` to `net8`.

```
Error   NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0.    Woodstock   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.321\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets
```

The good thing is that there is a link to a post that explain everything about the error `NETSDK1045`. The link to the post is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1045?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev17IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(NETSDK1045)%26rd%3Dtrue). As explained there, **This error occurs when the build tools can't find the version of the .NET SDK that's needed to build a project. This is typically due to a .NET SDK installation or configuration issue**

The issue I was facing was related to the configuration in the `global.json` file. So I did `dotnet --list-sdks` to see the installed versions. And update the version.

```
  "sdk": {
  "version": "8.0.201"
  }
```